# Post somente os relacionamento ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, restful, spring-jpa

Tenho as entidades escola e professor. Mapiei o relacionamento ManyToMany.
Não tenho ideia de como salvar somente a list passando um array de ids.

Classe Teacher

```
 @Id
 Long id;

 // não importa os demais atributos
```

Classe School:

```
@Id
Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "school_x_teacher", 
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_school"), 
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_teacher"))
private List<Teacher> teacher;
```

Quero envia via postman isso:

```
[
 { "id": 1},
{ "id": 2},
{ "id": 3}
]
```

o que diretamente no banco, salvando na escola com id = 1 seria:

> INSERT INTO school_x_teacher VALUES (1,1), (1,2),(1,3);

Answer (score 0):

Crie essa classe (a da join table) preencha com os dados que deseja e a envie via Json. Acho que é a solução mais fácil, porém não sei se é a melhor.

```
....sua ClasseDaJoinTable
private Long idSchool
private Long idTeacher

.... para enviar
List<ClasseDaJoinTable> valores = new ArrayList<>();
ClasseDaJoinTable classeDaJoinTable1 = new  ClasseDaJoinTable();
classeDaJoinTable1.setIdSchool(1);
classeDaJoinTable1.setIdTeacher(1);
valores.add(classeDaJoinTable1);
```

E retorne "valores" no seu metodo do rest controller. Espero que te ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Já experimentou passar o json corretamente?

```
   "teacher":[
       { "id": 1},
       { "id": 2},
       { "id": 3}
    ]
```